# Is it possible to search for text within the URLs of hyperlinks in Word?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm trying to use the Find dialog box to search for a specific URL. This Word document has hundreds of URLs, and rather than using the URL as the display name, the name of page is used for display purposes (I copied and pasted these links into the doc from a webpage since web browsers are most certainly incapable of this); thus, a regular "Find" search returns nothing so far as the contents of the hyperlinks' URLs.

For example, each of these are hyperlinks:[image]

Is there any way to search the actual URLs of hyperlinks in the documents? I know the domain of the website I need to find, but not the name of the page.

The solutions I see potentially feasible are:

1. Finding some way to convert all of the display names for each hyperlink to the URL rather than what it was manually changed to (either when pasting or afterwards)
2. Being able to search the URLs themselves

Is there a mechanism in Word that allows for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressing Alt+F9 toggle field codes and will show you codes instead of hyperlinks, they will look like e.g.

`{ HYPERLINK "http://superuser.com"}`

Now you can find them

Comment: If you press CTRL+A and Alt+F9, will this change all hyperlinks in a document to this format?

Comment: Yes, it'll change it, and pressing it again change them back